# Clustermembers on SPDS 4.3

Tags: sas

I am working with clustered datasets on SPDS 4.3.
I want to generate a list of the members for each cluster.
I found two possibilities to get the information I am looking for.
Either by using PROC CONTENTS and have a look on field "Cluster members are" or by using PROC SPDO like this:

```
  PROC SPDO LIBRARY=P30C033;  
    CLUSTER LIST LD_LIQ_CLUS_Customer;  
  QUIT;
```

In both cases I get the information in form of a report.
But I would like to get the information in form of a dataset.

I already tried out= and out2= on PROC CONTENTS, but dont get the desired output.
I also searchd for options to PROC SPDO CLUSTER LIST, but with no result.

Thx in advance
MiKe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a generic answer for any PROC, you can use ODS OUTPUT to get the dataset even if you can't use OUT= .

Add `ODS TRACE ON;` before the proc runs (and `ODS TRACE OFF` after it).  It should give you some results in the log telling you what the output is named; you can then use `ODS OUTPUT` to get the results.

For example, with PROC CONTENTS, run:

```
ods trace on;
proc contents data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Mabe you see that the `VARIABLES` table looks interesting to you.  So run:

```
ods output Variables=sasvars;
proc contents data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods output close;
```

`ODS TRACE` is not needed if you already know the name of the output portion, of course.

Comment: Thanks alot. For PROC CONTENTS your Solution works perfekt. PROC SPDO seems to work a little bit diffrent. It produces the following log entry:  
    NOTE: The PROCEDURE SPDO printed page 1.  
Is it possible to get this information in form of a dataset also?

Comment: I don't know anything about PROC SPDO, it's possible it doesn't work with the Output Delivery System as well as it ought to.  You might ask on communities.sas.com to see if one of the developers can answer that better.

Comment: Thanks again Joe, the guys at communities.sas.com had the answer. PROC PRINTTO print='Filename' writes the output of PROC SPDO (and other procs not using ODS for output) into the specified file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ODS OUTPUT CLUSTERLIST= as shown in the below code example:

```
ods noresults;
ods output clusterlist=WORK.CLUSTER_MEMS;
proc spdo lib=SPDSLIB;
   cluster list CLUSTER1;
   cluster list CLUSTER2;
   /* ... */
   cluster list CLUSTERN;
quit;
ods output close;
ods results;
```

This allows you to capture one or multiple clusters' members into a single data set.

You can also capture cluster members to separate data sets using OUT= option:

```
proc spdo lib=SPDSLIB;
   cluster list CLUSTER1 out=CLUSTER1_MEMBERS;
   cluster list CLUSTER2 out=CLUSTER2_MEMBERS;
   /* ... */
   cluster list CLUSTERN out=CLUSTERN_MEMBERS;
quit;
```

For more on this topic see my recent blog post [How to retrieve contents of a SAS® Scalable Performance Data Server library](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2019/09/16/how-to-retrieve-contents-of-sas-scalable-performance-data-server-library/).